# Complete MongoDB Uninstallation and Reinstallation with Homebrew on macOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I am encountering issues with MongoDB on my Mac using Homebrew, and despite multiple attempts to reinstall, the problem persists. I would like to completely remove all MongoDB-related components from my system and then perform a clean installation using Homebrew. The issues seem to be related to the MongoDB Community service running as the root user, leading to connection problems.

Here are the commands I tried so far:

1. Attempted MongoDB Installation using Homebrew:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

2. Starting MongoDB Community Service:

```
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

3. Unsuccessful MongoDB Service Status:

```
brew services list
```

Output:

```
Name              Status      User File
mongodb-community error  3584 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
unbound           none
```

Stopping MongoDB Service and Unloading LaunchAgent:

```
brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Attempted Reinstallation of MongoDB:

```
brew uninstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

Could someone kindly provide a step-by-step guide on how to thoroughly uninstall MongoDB, including its configurations and services, from a macOS system? Additionally, I need assistance with installing MongoDB correctly using Homebrew to avoid any issues with permissions and the MongoDB Community service running as the root user.

I am using macOS 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d), and I have already attempted reinstalling MongoDB via Homebrew, but the problem persists. Your help would be greatly appreciated, as I am eager to resolve this long-standing issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: If it's for dev, I'd install it with docker and forget about leftovers from brew uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue as of setting up mongodb-community

I installed version 7 and then wanted to move to version 5, in hindsight I would have installed version 5 without unistalling version 7 but now I have the same issue.

I have tried extensively to completely remove all traces of mongodb and do a clean install but I've had no success and so I'm hosting MongoBD in a docker container now.

I followed the following steps:

### install docker

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/

#### pull and host

> docker pull mongodb/mongodb-community-server:5.0-ubuntu2004

Pull the version of MongoDB relevant to your use case or leave out the colon and version to get the latest

> docker run --name mongo -d -p 27017:27017 mongodb/mongodb-community-server:5.0-ubuntu2004

now open up Mongo Compass and connect to the default URI, you should be good to go.